# Is there a native JS method for converting `+` and `/` to `-` and `_` prior to base64url encoding? What is it?

Tags: javascript, base64, jwt, base64url

I'm reading through a codebase and noticed the author manually uses replace to sanitize a string prior to base64url encoding, as per the base64url specification.

```
str = str.replace(/=+$/, ''); // remove padding equal characters
str = str.replace(/\+/g, '-'); // replace characters according to base64url specifications
str = str.replace(/\//g, '_'); // replace characters according to base64url specifications
```

Is there a native method for doing this? What is it?

Comment: @alfasin apparently this has to do with JWT specifically -- using base64url rather than base64, and I noticed JavaScript also doesn't have a native sha256 hashing algorithm, so I'm thinking it's possible W3C doesn't intend for JS to run on the server?

Comment: Look what googling `base64url javascript` found: https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url

Comment: @Adam Look at the package domain `npmjs.com`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In javascript there's encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent():

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: That was my first instinct, and I'm thinking there should be a similar method for converting with this specific JWT base64url ruleset (not including `%` etc). JWT is relatively new, so I'm thinking it's just not standardized by W3C, but eventually it might be